# In how many ways can the letters of the following word taken two at a time, be selected?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can the letters of the following word taken two at a time, be selected? 
'MONSOON'

In the word 'MONSOON', there are $3 O's$ and $2 N's$.
How could the selection be Made?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four unique letters here: $M,O,N,S$.

So the number of ways of choosing two distinct letters at a time is ${4 \choose 2} = 6$. We can then add the duplicate pairs which are $O,O$ and $N,N$ to give a total of $8$ possible pairs.

If we care about order (but without distinguishing between the three $O$s and two $N$s) then we have $4! = 24$ possible pairs of distinct letters, to which we once again add $2$ more to give 26 possible pairs with order.

Comment: Please try to elicit what the person who posted the question has attempted before answering the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry—I will try to do so next time.